# What can I call out a portion of the result return from Rouge?

Tags: python, nlp, rouge

Beginner here that needs help!

Tried googling but not much info

What should i do if I only want to return only the set of digits in rouge-l?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZX1U.png)

Comment: Links to and screenshots of code are not accepted on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question and add the code and the data it as **text**!

Comment: It would help if you show an example of what output you are expecting / trying to get, and/or any code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think rouge package allows it but you can just format the output:

```
formatted_scores = [{key: {k: "{0:.2f}".format(v) for k, v in value.items()} for key, value in s.items()} for s in scores]
print(formatted_scores)
```

> [{'rouge-1': {'f': '0.67', 'p': '0.67', 'r': '0.67'}, 'rouge-2': {'f':
>   '0.50', 'p': '0.50', 'r': '0.50'}, 'rouge-l': {'f': '0.67', 'p':
>   '0.67', 'r': '0.67'}}]